# Can I give a directory back to superuser?

Tags: terminal, sudo, terminal.app

I'm on macOS Sonoma. I was installing some Python and C packages in Homebrew, and it asked me to run:

```
sudo chown -R username /usr/local/opt
```

And:

```
chmod u+w /usr/local/opt
```

Now that I've installed the packages, how do I make myself not the owner of this so programs I run can't edit it?

Comment: Use root to assign the owner, group, and chmod as desired. Root always has override capabilities. You can also change the owner as the current owner to say root.

Comment: Why? If it is Homebrew, that is what is needed to make it run. Leave it alone. You’re fine.